# What's the difference between the words "plate" and "dish"?

Tags: word-choice, differences

I'm confused about the words *dish* and *plate*. Could someone please explain the difference?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A *plate* is a specific type of *dish*. A *dish* is generally something that food is eaten or served from. A *plate* tends to refer specifically to a flat dish that is suitable for holding food that does not have a high liquid content. The other common type of dish is a *bowl*. A *bowl* will be similar to a hollow sphere cut in half and is useful for serving soups and other foods with high liquid content which would run off of a plate.

A large plate intended for serving food may be referred to as a *platter*.

Comment: This is news to me. I'm a native speaker of American English and I've always considered "plate" and "dish" to be interchangeable.

Answer (score 20):

@aaronasterling gives a good explanation of what they mean as pieces of crockery.  They can also both mean — drat, I can’t find a good synonym now! — let’s say, menu items you might order at a restaurant:

> My favourite dish at the Murray Avenue Grill is their spinach salad with candied pecans.

or:

> The Ketchery has the best seafood plate in town.

These arose in obvious metonymy from the crockery usage, but have developed specific connotations.  *Dish* in this sense is much more general, and used (afaik) across most or all of the English-speaking world.  *Plate* is less usual, and more associated (I think) with North American usage, and with fancier restaurant subcultures.

Comment: Good point! I had totally forgotten about those usages. Defining words is not nearly as easy as it seems like it should be from the outside.

Answer (score 1):

DISH : 1. An open, generally shallow concave container for holding, cooking, or serving food.
       2. The food served or contained in a dish: a dish of ice cream.

PLATES : 1.A plate is a specific type of dish.
2.a shallow, usually circular dish, often of earthenware or porcelain, from which food is eaten.
3.the contents of such a dish; plateful.
4.an entire course of a meal served on such a dish: I had the vegetable plate for lunch.

Answer (score 1):

Like many other words in the English language, there is a confusion from time to time about the real, or exact, meaning of terms.  Here's what I think:

"Dish" is more of the generic term, as in "dish washer", "set of dishes", "main dish", etc.; however, while talking about dishes, cups are cups, saucers are saucers, bowls of any kind are always bowls, serving platters are always platters; however, in the group of dishes, there are "plates" which are noticeably larger than dishes and generally accommodate several kinds of food but are never used for serving food. One, I suppose, could call anything rather flat as a "dish" and never be wrong, which is not the case for "plate".