# What does "dish" really mean? Does it refer to a serving of food or a plate?

Tags: single-word-requests

Koreans will often say: "I had barbecue for lunch, with side dishes"

A Canadian English teacher says, 'You cannot say "I had barbecue for lunch with side dishes."  I would be thinking that you ate the plates.'

What about this question:
"What is your favorite Korean dish?" Is it correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between the words "plate" and "dish"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6276/whats-the-difference-between-the-words-plate-and-dish)

Comment: '= plate', literal; '= food', metaphor. Both meanings are **standard** English now. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dish

Answer (score 4):

*[**Dish**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/dish?q=dish)* can correspond to either the physical plate or the food item, depending on the context. A *[**side dish**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/side-dish?q=side%20dish)* refers to a food item that accompanies the main course.

It is perfectly fine to say:

> I had barbecue for lunch with side dishes.
>
> What is your favorite Korean dish?

Comment: OP is quite a dish too if I may say so:)

Comment: I wouldn't agree with OP's teacher (if the context is as it seems) but I'd link items of equivalent 'status': 'For lunch, I had barbecued king prawns and pork chops, with side dishes'. Possibly a dash could bridge the non-equivalents 'I had a barbecue – with side dishes'. (The massified usage 'have barbecue' isn't one I'm familiar with [I'm in the UK and ancient], but may of course be becoming common. A Google search for "had barbecue for" does show quite a few hits. 'Have a curry' has certainly massified to 'have curry [for tea].) >>Ah, ODO flags the mass noun usage as an Americanism.

Answer (score 2):

**A side dish:**

sometimes referred to as a side order, side item, or simply a side,**is a food item that accompanies the entrée or main course at a meal.**

Source: Collins Dictionary

Probably there was some misunderstanding with you teacher.

Answer (score 1):

Both meanings are correct, and should be understood in context. Here's a definition from [merriam-webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dish):

> 1. a shallow container that you cook or serve food in; specifically : a shallow bowl
> 2. the food served in a dish
> 3. food that is prepared in a particular way

This is probably a case of [metonymy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy), which is "a figure of speech in which a thing or concept is called not by its own name but rather by the name of something associated in meaning with that thing or concept". So you have food that is prepared and served, and a word that can describe the food, the container, or both of them together.

I will leave it up to the reader to decide which of the definitions is the original, if any is at all, and which was metonymically derived.

Answer (score 0):

The earlier Collins dictionary example "...or simply a side,..." is not so commonly heard in UK English usage. In the UK it would more usually be "...or simply a side dish,..."
Dish in UK English can refer to either the food or the dish it is placed on, or both.

Richard D.

Answer (score 0):

There is a cultural difference here which may have caused your confusion over the usage of the words.

A typical Korean meal, for example Kalbi, would have the main beef dish in the middle of the table and several other dishes - the side dishes - containing vegetables and garnish around the table.  The diners take their food from all the dishes present.

A typical Western meal would be served on one plate with a separate plate - a side dish - for items such as bread.  The diners each have their own side dish.  Although when dining in an Indian or Chinese restaurant this may vary.

The term *side dish* has the meanings that other answers have provided.  It can be used for both the item of crockery and the food upon it in all types of cuisine.  However, the cultural nuance may have caused confusion.  Especially over the difference in the manner of barbecues between Korea and Canada.