# What is the name of a group of foods that are not cuisine, cooking technique or ingredient specific?

Tags: single-word-requests, lists, collective-nouns, food

What would the name for a list of foods that are not specific to cuisine, cooking technique or ingredient?

This is a question about how to precisely categorize foods using plain English.
A curry is a generic name of a dish that has the following, very broad characteristics:

> Cuisine: Indian, Thai, Japanese
>
> Cooking technique: stewed, slow cooked
>
> Characteristics: spiced, wet,
>
> Ingredients: spices, a protein, vegetables, stock

As we can see, it can't be categorized by features like its ingredients, cuisine etc. There are lots of dishes that have these broad definitions (soup, salad, burger, cake etc). "Dish" is too unspecific, as under the heading of curry there are korma, pathia etc and these are dishes in their own right. What should I call a list of these broad, cuisine-spanning names?

Comment: ***Edible*** items ?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6276/whats-the-difference-between-the-words-plate-and-dish/6299#6299

Comment: "Menu item" or "Food Category" (https://www.islandsrestaurants.com/food) or "Menu Category" or "Food Type" or "Plate" or simply "Food"

Answer (score 2):

They are simply **dishes**. Some dishes may be specific to certain cuisines, or otherwise identifiable in your categories, but based on the examples you give, *dish* seems to be the simplest word encompassing all of them.

*grocery (list)*, as mentioned in a comment is *not* a valid description, as it would apply only to people who buy these dishes in a ready-made version. When talking about cooking, grocery refers to ingredients, not the finished product.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I don't think dish works as it is too unspecific. Within the category of dish there is korma, madras ect so it needs to be less specific please.

Comment: @ZiggyBracey: If _dish_ is too **unspecific**, but you _ask_ for something **less specific**, I don't understand what you mean ;)

Comment: @ZiggyBracey Agreed with oerkelen's confusion. Also, can you describe the distinction you're drawing between korma and madras? I'm not very familiar with those foods, but I think korma is the *dish* and madras merely a sauce? If it's just a sauce, then it's not a dish. Perhaps you're looking for something a bit more emphatic? *Prepared dish*, perhaps?

Comment: @DanBron Sorry for being unclear! :D Korma and madras are two types of curry that have different ingredients and flavors. They fall equally under the heading of curry because they adhere to the other characteristics I listed above. A sauce would be a component of a curry so ranked underneath dish. What I'm looking for is the name of a categorization ranked above dish. if that makes sense.

Comment: @ZiggyBracey  Ok! I think I got it. You want something like a hypernym for *entree*, *appetizer*, *dessert*, etc. I'm not sure *course* is exactly what you're looking for, but we're getting closer.

Comment: @DanBron Defiantly getting closer, thank you so much for your help! A course isn't right because that is the _point in a meal_ that you would eat a dish. Terms like curry are themselves hypernyms, so in effect I need a hypernym to describe a hypernym. :/

Comment: @ZiggyBracey: still failing to understand what you are looking for. Your examples include curry, soup and salad. All of those are _dishes_. Every curry is a dish. Now you disagree because there are several different _curries_? Dow you want a word for something that includes all curries and excludes all other things, or a word that includes all curries, but also all salads, soups, etc.? Dish is a hypernym for curry, soup; curry is a hypernym for korma, madras. At what level are you looking for another hypernym now? For _dish_ and something else? Then what _is_ that something else?

Comment: @oerkelens haha, I don't know what that something else is, hence my question! I'm looking for the word which includes all curries, soups, salads etc but is higher level than individual dishes like korma.

Comment: But _curry_, _salad_ and _soup_ are all dishes, as is _korma_, or "Specialty of the chef; korma prepared with special home grown herbs and spices". _Dish_ does most certainly not stop at the level of korma. It seems you limit the meaning of _dish_ to "specific preparation of a dish that can be found on a restaurant menu", but that is not the full meaning of _dish_.

Comment: If you talk about "the dishes that this restaurant offers", yes, _dish_ functions at the _korma_ level. But you can also use it in "there were so many different dishes at the buffet: soups, salads, curries, roasts... and so many more dishes that I cannot even remember!"

Answer (score 1):

You should make your question more clear. Where are you planning to use this list?

I'd simply call the list **refreshments**

If you're looking for something really fancy, try **[comestibles](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/comestible#comestible__3)**

> An item of food:
>
> *a fridge groaning with comestibles*

[Oxford]

---

EDIT: Thanks for updating your question. After reading it, I think you want to describe something like curry, but your beef with calling it, say, 'of Indian cuisine', is that curry isn't exclusive to any one cuisine.

I hate to suggest neologisms, but I think your best bet here is cross-cuisine.

As in: *Tandoori is definitely Indian, but curry is cross-cuisine.*

Comment: With _refreshment_, I think of something to _drink_, not something to eat. _Comestibles_ applies to (eatable) ingredients, not (exclusively) to fully-prepared dishes.

Comment: @oerkelens: Agree with the 2nd point. Disagree with the 1st. Can't speak for BrE and AmE, but InE speakers will be sorely disappointed if promised refreshments and offered just (non-alcoholic) drinks.

Comment: Well, I get your point, but I doubt you can actually disagree with the statement that _I think of something to drink_ ;) But it's good to know that food can be included in _refreshments_, at least in some cases :)

Comment: @oerkelens: No I can't :). And if you ever host a social gathering in India, I advise you to include food in _refreshments_ in ALL cases.

Comment: I will keep it in mind :) So far I have only had the pleasure of being a guest at such events.

Comment: @TusharRaj Perfect, thank you so much! Cross-cuisine is pretty much exactly what I meant. Don't suppose you can think of synonyms that Joe Bloggs is more likely to recognise?

Comment: @ZiggyBracey: Not at the moment, no. But I'll keep thinking.